# Scaling JavaScript output without the loss of properties or pixels

Tags: jquery, css, scale

I just was able to make a nice map with my sql statement: 
http://webpages.avans.nl/acue-gast01/database/index.html

However the 'image' or the dimension of the output is way to large.

I'm wondering, how am I able to center and scale the "image" down without losing the dots (which are crucial) and their respective position?. I tried in to set the body to a size (I ammended the script to the body) but it didn't work.

Here is my JQuery:

```
$.getJSON("index.php", function(data) {
//laat data in console zien
console.log(data);

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    //laat data per item console zien
    console.log(key + " - " + "Lengtegraad" + ": " + val.Airport_LONG + " | " + "Breedtegraad" + ": " + val.Airport_LAT);
var number;
function repeat() {
    number = Math.floor((Math.random()*1)+9);
    setTimetout(repeat, 1000);
}

$("<div>").html("")
.css('right', -val.Airport_LONG*10 + "px")
.css('bottom', val.Airport_LAT*10 + "px")
.appendTo("body");
});
```

and my CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    height: 800px;
    width: 600px;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}


div {
height: 1px;
width: 1px;
position: absolute;
background-color:#FFF;

}
```

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: I amended the post. Hopefully it is better now. I would love to have it answered

Comment: What I would do is create some kind of ratio. First take the real width and the real height of your image then apply this ratio to each dot your created.

Comment: But how do I find out what the size of the image that java script draws is?..

Comment: The script you have included in your question is more 'JQuery' than 'JavaScript'. Though they're both fundamentally the same thing, JQuery is "unique-wish." I have edited your question to state the script as JQuery.